# Monogame: Assets not being loaded after changing the properties

Tags: c#, monogame

I am using VS2015 and monogame

**Before anything, I have searched for my question, and I have followed the steps those answers told me to. I have changed the .xnb files' build action to "Content" and Copy to Output directory to "Copy if newer".**

Unfortunately I am still getting the error that "Could not load Content\Graphics\burger asset as a non-content file!" While highlighting the following line:

```
  sprite = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(spriteName);
```

*Could not load Content\Graphics\burger asset as a non-content file!* is what I get when I check the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Apparently, or at least for this particular code which I had received, what worked was **adding the content directly on the monogame content pipeline (present in your slm file) and building that**, instead of adding the converted .xnb files externally after building them on monogame serperately. I wish I knew why this happened, because previously loading xnb files externally worked perfectly, but this is how I got my desired output. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic problem and there is some details missing, so I'm going to give you many solutions.

If you are using the MGCB program that comes with MonoGame, you should just put the original .png or .jpg file in the directory and let MGCB convert it to .xnb for you.

If you don't have the original, or you must use the .xnb, just set the build action to Do Nothing and Copy If Newer. Since it's already a .xnb file, you don't need to do anything to it.

You could also have the file path wrong. I don't know what spriteName is, but it should be:

```
sprite = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/burger");
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I have already converted the files to .xnb format. and this lines comes in the cs file for the burger method, which is why the spriteName is there. My resources for the sprites are already .xnb files.